# How to sort test by modification time in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

How to override Rspec default ordering to run test by file modification time?

Comment: Modification time of your spec files or the files under test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this configuration to you `test_helper`/`spec_helper`/`rails_helper`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.register_ordering(:global) do |items|
    items.sort_by { |item| -File.mtime(item.metadata[:absolute_file_path]).to_i }
  end
end
```

**Explanation:** Rspec lets you to define custom ordering with `config.resgister_orderdering`. In this case we're overriding the global config. All you have to do is to pass a block where you define your custom ordering function.

- `item.metadata[:absolute_file_path]` gets the file path of your test file.
- `File.mtime` gets the modification time of a file and the minus sign is to reverse ordering them